# Nodejs change global variable inside mysql query

Tags: mysql, node.js

i'm trying to create a nodejs server but the following code is not working any advice?

```
var app = require('http').createServer();
var io = require('socket.io')(app);
var mysql = require('mysql');

var dblists = new Array();
pool=mysql.createPool({host : host,user : user,password: pass });   
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    connection.query("use nodejs");
    connection.query('SELECT db_name,domain_name FROM tbl_dblist;',
    function (err, rows,f) {
        rows.forEach(function (entry) {
            dblists[entry["domain_name"]] = entry["db_name"];
        });
    });
});

console.log(dblists);
```

Thanks in advance]
The whole code:

```
var dblists = new Array();

app.listen(3000);
var xsocket = io.listen(app);
//console.log('Listen On Port 3000');
var pool=mysql.createPool({host : host,user : user,password: pass });   

pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    connection.query("use nodejs");
    connection.query('SELECT db_name,domain_name FROM tbl_dblist;',
    function (err, rows,f) {
        rows.forEach(function (entry) {
            dblists[entry["domain_name"]] = entry["db_name"];
        });
    });
});


xsocket.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, callback) {
    callback(null, true);
});


xsocket.on('connection', function (conn) {
    xsocket.emit('list',dblists);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getConnection` is asynchronous, so your `console.log` fires before you get any values in your array.

If you put the `console.log` inside the method, it will work as epxected:

```
xsocket.on('connection', function (conn) {    
    pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
        connection.query("use nodejs");
        connection.query('SELECT db_name,domain_name FROM tbl_dblist;',
        function (err, rows,f) {
            rows.forEach(function (entry) {
                dblists[entry["domain_name"]] = entry["db_name"];
            });
            xsocket.emit('list', dblists);
        });
    });        
});
```

Comment: So there is no way for debugging?

Comment: Why? You will have your values inside the function. If you need a `synchronous` way, then you should probably look at `async` library

Comment: The problem is even if i emit the dblists i'm not getting anythin in my client

Comment: You will need to send the data to the client inside the callback. Can you post the whole code or have you tried my suggestion>

Comment: @FarshidMehrtash I've updated my answer. You will need to emit inside your callback in order to get results.

Comment: The reason i'm Trying to make an array is i'm making this server query based and query value will be the index of the array and then i'll call another function , the needed answer is in that function

Comment: This is an asynchronous world, to get everything working you need to use callback and you will get appropriate values inside these callbacks.

Comment: My approach to this problem was wrong.Thanks for the tip

Comment: i am having the same problem but i am using create connected he is using create pool makes difference?

Comment: @ujwaldhakal I don't think it's much different